# Exporting report to PDF using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, pdf, reports

My script works fine, but I am not able to export .pdf file from a report generated. This is my code:

```
import arcpy

inputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
matricula = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

query = """ "MATRICULA" LIKE '%s'""" %matricula 

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Prueba/arcpy"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inputFC,"Tramos_LAT_layer")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Tramos_LAT_layer","NEW_SELECTION",query)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("Tramos_LAT_layer",outputFC)

# Following I try to export report from outputFC

# RLF
plantilla = "PLANTILLA_INFORMES.rlf"

# PDF
pdf = "zz_salida_report.pdf"

# Exportamos Report
arcpy.mapping.ExportReport(outputFC,plantilla,pdf)
```

I also tested another option, I created a layer file, but it didn´t work either:

```
lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(outputFC)

arcpy.mapping.ExportReport(lyr,plantilla,pdf)
```

I have checked all post about this issue, although I don't understand why my script doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using full paths to point to PLANTILLA_INFORMES.rlf and also for the output zz_salida_report.pdf? The documented examples all use fully qualified paths - http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000062000000

Comment: The documentation also says it must reference a Layer or TableView object. A Layer object can either be a reference to a .lyr file or a layer in a map document. The outputFC should be in an mxd and a reference made to it. See the examples in the link above

Comment: Thank you so much. You are right, I have used full paths to point to "file".rlf and "file".pdf and it works !! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: However, I still don't understand why didn't work it, because I used a workspace (arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Prueba/arcpy"). Thanks

Comment: Excellent, I have added it as an answer if you can give it a green tick of approval. I tried to find info for workspace and the tool but couldn't find any. It was only when I saw the examples with full paths that I thought that workspace might not work for the input and output of the tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documented examples for [ExportReport](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000062000000) use full paths for the report_layout_file and output_file parameters (2nd and 3rd parameters)

Change the code to reflect this

```
# RLF
plantilla = "full_path/PLANTILLA_INFORMES.rlf"

# PDF
pdf = "full_path/zz_salida_report.pdf"
```